# nginx large file upload limit

Tags: nginx, php, upload, laravel

I am using Laravel Forge to manage my server and I had a problem with uploading large files with livewire.
after 100 seconds uploadng fails and shows this error:

```
net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED
```

and sometimes:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

my PHP timeout is 1000 and upload file size is 1.5 GB but I don't know why this happens.
I tried setting these in my nginx configuration but it did not help.

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
client_header_timeout 1m;
client_body_timeout 1m;
proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
proxy_read_timeout 1m;
proxy_send_timeout 1m;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was not nginx problem, Kaspersky on my system was killing the requests.

I hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error logs for nginx for details (Probably `/var/log/nginx/error.log`), but it might be as simple as needing to set: `client_max_body_size 2g` in nginx config.

Comment: There is nothing in the logs and I already increased client_max_body_size but it did not work.